# If Outlook Subject and Date Received

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using vba from excel to search my default outlook inbox for emails that contain "Weekly Op's Report for" on the subject line and transfer to excel. How can I modify my code to meet to conditions: if subject line reads "Weekly Op's Report for" and Received date = today then copy email body. Here is my code below:

```
Sub GetFromInbox()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items

olItms.Sort "Subject"

i = 1

For Each olMail In olItms
    If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, "Weekly Op's Report for ") > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tester").Cells(i, 1).Value = olMail.Body
        i = i + 1

    End If
Next olMail

Set olFldr = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ReceivedTime property of olMail object to achieve your request. Please try this code below:

```
Sub GetFromInbox()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim date1 As String
Dim date2 As String

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items
date1 = Date
olItms.Sort "Subject"
olItms.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

i = 1

For Each olMail In olItms
date2 = olMail.ReceivedTime
If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, "Weekly Op's Report for ") > 0 And DateDiff("d", date1, date2) = 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tester").Cells(i, 1).Value = olMail.Body
    i = i + 1

End If
Next olMail

Set olFldr = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

For more DateDiff function, please see [How to use the DATEDIFF Function (VBA)](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php).

Comment: getting an object required error on `Set date1 = Date`

Comment: Sorry, please remove "Set". Like this date1 = Date
date2 = olMail.ReceivedTime

Comment: sorry, I am a little confused as to which one I am supposed to remove

Comment: Set date1 = Date Instead  date1 = Date



Set date2 = olMail.ReceivedTime Instead date2 = olMail.ReceivedTime