# Retrieve e-mail body content depending on subject and cell value in a column

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to retrieve the content of an email with a certain subject which is linked to a cell value in a different column.

Code from [If Outlook Subject and Date Received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941798/if-outlook-subject-and-date-received) works with the exception of range.
Instead of one cell value (ex. A1) I want to retrieve from the full column A. So that for each value in column A (which is in this case the date) the content of the e-mail which contains as subject "always the same title" & "date of cells in column A".

Example
A1 = 16/08/2019 ==> e-mail subject = 16/08Title ==> B2 = content of said e-mail
A2 = 20/08/2019 ==> e-mail subject = 20/08Title ==> B2 = content of said e-mail

```
Sub GetFromInbox ()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant 
Dim i As Long

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = OlFldr.Items

olItms.Sort "Subject"
i =1

For Each olMail In olItms
    If InStr (1, olMail.Subject, "Subject" & Range ("A1") > 0 Then 
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,2).Value = olMail.Body
        i = i + 1
     End If
 Next olMail

 Set olFldr = Nothing
 Set olNs = Nothing
 Set olApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

I tried changing Range ("A1") to range ("A:A").

This gives

> runtime error 13: Type mismatch

I tried different ways to offset.

```
Sub GetFromInbox ()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant 
Dim i As Long

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = OlFldr.Items

olItms.Sort "Subject"
i =1

For Each olMail In olItms
    If InStr (1, olMail.Subject, "Subject" & Range ("A1") > 0 Then 
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,2).Value = olMail.Body
        i = i + 1
    End If
 Next olMail

 Set olFldr = Nothing
 Set olNs = Nothing
 Set olApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: Does the text **"Subject"** appear within the subject of the email? (i.e. **"Subject16/08/2019"**). **NOTE**: there is no space between the date and the text.. is that how the text appear in `Subject`?

Comment: Hi Zac, yes that is how the text appears as subject in the e-mail "Subject16/08/2019" without a space.

Answer (score 0):

Create a for loop that will loop through all of the rows of column A.

```
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
'Finding the last row in Column A    
For Each olMail In olItms
    For j = 1 To LastRow
      If InStr (1, olMail.Subject, "Subject" & Range ("A" & j) > 0 Then 
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,2).Value = olMail.Body
         i = i + 1
      End If
    Next j
Next olMail
```

Comment: For performance reason, I would capture the values from column a in a dictionary then have a single loop to check all emails in 1 loop

Comment: Unfortunately I now get syntax error for both the original code as the adapted one for the following  'If InStr (1, olMail.Subject, "Subject" & Range ("A" & j) > 0 Then'. Does anyone know what could be causing this?